# How can I pass a javascript value to php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to add a javascript value to my php query. The code goes like this

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
    var categoryName = $(this).html();

    <?php
         $one = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM tb_category WHERE category_name = '?' ");
    ?>

    })

</script>
```

I want to put the value of categoryName to the query which I made in php. How will I do it.

Comment: You could do an AJAX call and send the data to a separate PHP file that deals with your database query.

Answer (score 0):

Just spend a few hours trying to figure this out myself today. You can use ajax, and send the information using the data tag in an ajax query.

```
   $.ajax({ url: 'file goes here',
          data: {action: '0'},
          type: 'post',
       success: function(output) { //action }
    });
```

The data tag gives you the information.
In your php:

```
$data = $_POST["action"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var categoryName = $(this).text(); 
    // !! be careful here !! send web safe category name, `$(this).text();` or even better a numeric value.
    $.get('runquery.php', {'category': encodeURIComponent(categoryName)}).done(function (data) {
        // on success do something if needed
    });
})
</script>
```

Put your PHP/SQL script in runquery.php

Comment: It would not always work if you don't `encodeURI` the `categoryName` in the GET request URL. What you could also do is: `$.get('runquery.php', {'category': categoryName}, function (data) {});`

Comment: he didn't ask us to do all his work. for example i didn't correct his sql query to prevent sql injection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: indeed. I was suggesting it for the community :) (AJAX calls are a bit tricky for early beginners anyway)

Answer (score 0):

you should use ajax to get the attribute from your clicked div and send it to a php page where you receive the "javascript variable" and use it as a php variable with $_POST like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {   
 $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
 {
 var categoryname = $(this).attr("id");   
 var dataString = 'categoryname'+ categoryname ;


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "yourphppage.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(html)
{

$(".result").html(html);  
} 
});


return false;
});
});
```

Now in your php page:

```
     $categoryname=$_POST['categoryname'];

     $one = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM tb_category WHERE category_name = $categoryname   
     ");
```

Comment: but how i can I get the data from the query?? I want it because i want to use it to these code

echo "$('#region').val('" . $rowOne['category_name'] . "');";

Comment: you can return the data resulting from the query in a div, you select the div in the success function $(".result").html(html); create an empty div and give it a class name "result" now the result of the query will be loaded into the div of class "result"

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't go this way, unless you make **AJAX calls** (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ and other answers).

The **simplest solution** (if you do not have too many categories, say a few hundreds tops) would be to cache the categories client-side in a Javascript variable, as in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var categoriesCache = <?php
        $cache = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, category_name FROM tb_category");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $cache[$row["category_name"]] = $row["id"];
        }
        echo json_encode($cache);
    ?>;
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
        var categoryName = $(this).html();
        var categoryId = categoriesCache[categoryName];
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Ajax 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Php-script in a separate File like:

First you JavaScript file:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
var categoryName = $(this).html();
  $.post("php-file.php",{cat_Name: categoryName});
});
```

then you php-file.php looks like:

```
<?php
     $categoryname = $_POST['cat_Name'];
     $one = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM tb_category WHERE category_name = '?' ");
?>
```

if you want to use them again:

add to your PHP on the end:

```
$return = new array();
$return[0] = ;//your results in this array
echo json_encode($return);
```

then in your JavaScript should look like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
    var categoryName = $(this).html();
      $.post("php-file.php",{cat_Name: categoryName}, function(data){
          sccess_function(data);}, "json");
});
```

then add a function:

```
function succsess_function(data){
    //do thing here

}
```